# Adding Click Event Listener to Adobe Data Layer in React

Tags: reactjs, adobe-analytics

I'm just starting to enter the world of Adobe Analytics. I'm working in React with Typescript and I am trying to leverage the adobe data layer to send information to Adobe Launch. I've been able to successfully use the adobe push function (i.e. `window.adobeDataLayer.push({ test: 'test succeeded' })`) and can both see that in the console via `window.adobeDataLayer.getState()` and ran a simple test to confirm it made its way to Adobe Launch.

However, when it comes to adding an event listener, I'm stumped. I attempted to follow [Adobe's Documentation](https://github.com/adobe/adobe-client-data-layer/wiki#addeventlistener) and came up with the following (doStuff() was just to confirm that eventListeners were working as expected, which they do):

```
function myHandler(event: any): void {
  console.log("My handler was called")
}

function doStuff() {
  console.log('do stuff was called')
}
function adobeAnalyticsTest(): void {
  console.log(' adobeAnalyticsTest function called')

  window.adobeDataLayer = window.adobeDataLayer || []
  window.adobeDataLayer.push({ test: 'test succeeded' })

  window.addEventListener('click', doStuff)

  window.adobeDataLayer.push(function (dl: any) {
    dl.getState()
    dl.addEventListener('click', myHandler)
  })

}
useEffect(() => {
  adobeAnalyticsTest()
}, [])
```

Looking at window.adobeDataLayer, I couldn't see anything that seemed to indicate there was a click event listener (although this could be ignorance on my part) nor was 'My Handler was called' ever logged to the console. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong or know how to tell when it's working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At face value, it looks like you don't have anything in your code that actually calls `adobeAnalyticsTest()`.

Also, the listener you attach to `dl` doesn't listen for DOM events like clicking on something in `window` (like your `window.addEventListener` line); it listens for payloads pushed to `adobeDataLayer` where the passed `event` property value matches what you are listening for.

For example, put `adobeDataLayer.push({'event':'click'})` in your js console you should see "My handler was called".

Think of it more like subscribing to a `CustomEvent` (because that's what it is, under the hood), rather than a native DOM event.

Comment: I do call `adobeAnalyticsTest()` in an useEffect, and I'll update my example above to reflect that. 

So, if my data layer is set up to listen for when a click event is pushed to the data layer, I might as well use a classic event listener like doStuff() and just add an adobeDataLayer.push() there. 

I tried pushing a click event and did see console statement in myHandler get called.

Perhaps I'm missing the obvious, but what's an actual use case for adding an event listener to the data layer?

Comment: @Natalka  AA (and other analytics tools such as google analytics) isn't really about tracking DOM events; it's about tracking user activity.  You as the site stakeholder define events from a user experience (UX) perspective. Some classic examples: Page View, Form View / Complete, Search and events. So in practice, you'd listen for and push stuff like `events:'pageView'` or `events:'formSubmit'`, along with payloads relevant to it (e.g. maybe user id/login status info, form name, etc.)

Comment: .. and these UX events _may_ line up with DOM events sometimes. For example, listening for a link click to track exit links, or video events (e.g. play, pause, stop) that there are established DOM events to leverage. But most the time, your KPIs don't really have direct DOM counterparts representing the KPI.  So you create custom events that accurately represent your given KPI and broadcast it at appropriate times, and listen for them in the data layer.

Comment: Also in practice, you usually do not directly add event listeners on a code level like you have in your code. Instead, you create Rules in your tag manager (e.g. Adobe Launch), which under the hood, do the same thing, but it's a more user-friendly non-coder friendly interface.

Comment: For example, let's say you want to track form views in AA. You have event1 assigned in AA, and you have eVar1 assigned as your form name eVar. You'd create a data layer event based rule in launch that says listen for pushes where event=='formView'. Then in the Rule action area, you'd pick the AA set events/vars action, specify event1, and let's say you also push form.name='some form' in that data layer push, so you map form.name to eVar1 (e.g. you can create a Data Element for this and then map the DE to eVar1 in the action), and then add an AA send beacon action.

Comment: and then you do whatever code logic on your end to determine when your form is viewed (could be something as simple as DOM Ready on a specific URL your form lives on; this will be unique to your site/implementation needs), and at appropriate time, call `adobeDataLayer.push({'event':'formView','form': {'name':'some form'}});` and the rule you setup in Launch under the hood basically does the `window.adobeDataLayer.push(function (dl: any) {  dl.getState();dl.addEventListener('click', myHandler) })` part of your code for you, and the Action part of your rule equates to your `myHandler` callback

Comment: sidenote: yes, in this example, you could instead just skip all this and configure your launch rule to trigger on dom ready, with a condition for the url. But pushing stuff through a data layer like this is more about following a certain practice, not bringing some net-new functionality to the table. But that's a whole other discussion.

Comment: thank you for the additional information. This implementation is starting with developers, but I could see the appeal of trying to have more control for adobe analytics from Launch rather than the code base itself.